# How to change attributes of element in EJS in dynamicly

Tags: jquery, attributes, ejs

I have been strugling with this problem for quite a while. I was trying to use jQuery in my EJS to change the attributes of elements. However after a longtime of search on Google, I still can not solve this problem.

As my title said, I'm willing to change the "id" of the button and "data-target" in div from "collapseOne" to "request._id" in a foreach loop so that the attribute changes in each iteration . Please see my code below

```
    <% outboundList.forEach(function(requests){ %>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button id="outboundListTitle" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="">
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#outboundListTitle').attr("aria-controls", requests._id)
              $('#outboundListTitle').attr("data-target", requests._id)
            </script>

            <%= requests.clientName %>_<%= requests.wareHouseLabel %>_<%= requests.oldSku %>_<%= requests.productQt %>
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div name='outboundListContent' class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion" id="collapseOne" >
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $( "div[name~='outboundListContent']" ).attr("id", requests._id)
        </script>
        <div class="card-body">
         
----- some content ----

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the attribute with <%= request._id%> to replace the if and datta-target, but this seems not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're still stuck with this issue, it can be easily fixed by using single or double quotation('') around the variable.

In your case just place single quotes around the variable

```
$('#outboundListTitle').attr("data-target", '<%= request._id%>')
```

Because, you want the value of that variable to be displayed over there, thus, using the quotations will first evaluate what the value of that variable is then move further.
For more reference you can read [docs](https://ejs.co/#docs)

Comment: If the id is repeated, then jQuery will not find all the matching elements.

Comment: That's correct, in that case simply assign a 'class' and use 'this' keyword to target the current element.

Comment: You could solve that as well by changing your selector to `$('[id=outboundListTitle]')`